R, why does Dunn post hoc test detect a significant difference in abundance only in the pair of years that look the most similar?
I cannot understand why my Dunn test post hoc test, after a significant kruskal-wallis test, is detecting a significant difference in years 2022 and 2023, when they appear to have the most similar distribution of total abundance across sites. I would think the difference should actually be significant for 2021-2022 and 2021-2023. Can someone explain this please?
My results:
>shapiro.test(summary$Abundance)
data:  summary$Abundance
W = 0.49864, p-value = 1.742e-09

>kruskal.test(Abundance ~ Year, data=summary)
data:  Abundance by Year
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 9.817, df = 2, p-value = 0.007384

>dunnTest(summary$Abundance, summary$Year, method="bonferroni")
      Comparison          Z     P.unadj      P.adj
1 2021 - 2022 -0.8256766 0.408987553 1.00000000
2 2021 - 2023  2.2707925 0.023159544 0.06947863
3 2022 - 2023  2.8414068 0.004491497 0.01347449  # How??

Here is my data table. The Abundance column is how many individuals were collected at each site.
> dput(summary)
structure(list(Genus = c("Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", 
"Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", 
"Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", 
"Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", 
"Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", 
"Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Ceratina"
), Sex = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M"), Year = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), levels = c("2021", "2022", "2023"), class = "factor"), SiteID = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 17L, 18L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 27L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L), levels = c("H02", "H03", "H04", 
"H05", "H06", "H07", "H08", "H09", "L01", "L02", "L04", "L05", 
"L06", "L07", "L08", "L09", "L10", "L12", "M01", "M02", "M03", 
"M04", "M05", "M06", "M08", "M09", "M10", "M11", "M12"), class = "factor"), 
    ITD.avg = c(1.089, 1.155, 1.199, 1.32, 1.21, 1.17203225806452, 
    1.3695, 1.188, 1.089, 1.1913, 1.111, 1.21025, 1.3068125, 
    1.17591666666667, 1.3081, 1.27319444444444, 1.17591666666667, 
    1.326125, 1.245, 1.162, 1.1952, 1.2948, 1.2948, 1.23788571428571, 
    1.245, 1.1205, 1.1205, 1.245, 1.0458, 1.2699, 1.1703, 1.245, 
    1.245), WW.Avg = c(0.666666666666667, 2, 1, 0, 3.33333333333333, 
    0.709677419354839, 0, 0, 2, 3.9, 0, 1.75, 0.25, 1.5, 0.95, 
    1.16666666666667, 1.33333333333333, 3, 1, 2.16666666666667, 
    4, 5, 4.5, 2.07142857142857, 0.75, 5, 3.25, 2, 1.5, 3, 3.5, 
    1, 4), Abundance = c(3, 2, 3, 1, 6, 31, 2, 1, 2, 10, 3, 2, 
    4, 3, 10, 9, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 7, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    1, 1)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -33L), groups = structure(list(Genus = c("Ceratina", 
"Ceratina", "Ceratina"), Sex = c("M", "M", "M"), Year = structure(1:3, levels = c("2021", 
"2022", "2023"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:11, 
    12:18, 19:33), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))

And if I plot the distribution of total abundance per site across the years, 2022 and 2023 look the most similar...


You are being misled by the plot to compare apples and oranges. If you want to have a visual sense of the differences between years, if any exist, use a box-and-whiskers plot instead.
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(summ, aes(Year, Abundance)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_bw()


Created on 2024-10-30 with reprex v2.1.1
It seems that year 2023 is, on average, different. You can now test this with an ANOVA or its non-parametric equivalent, a Kruskal-Wallis test.
The Kruskal-Wallis test of abundance on year below shows a significant difference in the groups by year so a post-hoc Dunn test can be applied.
kruskal.test(Abundance ~ Year, summ)
#> 
#>  Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test
#> 
#> data:  Abundance by Year
#> Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 9.817, df = 2, p-value = 0.007384
FSA::dunnTest(Abundance ~ Year, summ)
#> Dunn (1964) Kruskal-Wallis multiple comparison
#>   p-values adjusted with the Holm method.
#>    Comparison          Z     P.unadj      P.adj
#> 1 2021 - 2022 -0.8256766 0.408987553 0.40898755
#> 2 2021 - 2023  2.2707925 0.023159544 0.04631909
#> 3 2022 - 2023  2.8414068 0.004491497 0.01347449

Created on 2024-10-30 with reprex v2.1.1

Note
This is a case where I prefer base graphics. It's a much simpler one-liner with no need to load an extra package.
boxplot(Abundance ~ Year, summ)


Created on 2024-10-30 with reprex v2.1.1

Oh I see...but the boxplot still shows me that 2021 and 2022 are very similar, yet why don't we see that 2021-2023 is also significant like 2022-2023? Is it simply because some of the values in 2021 overlap more with 2023 (the bottom whisker of 2021)?

@KatherineChau I don't understand your comment, 2021-2023 has a p-value of 0.023 and an adj-p-value of 0.04631909, still significant at the 0.05 level. 2023 is clearly below the other two years.

I don't understand how my results (posted above) are coming up different from yours?

@KatherineChau It's due to a mistake from my part, I forgot to use method="bonferroni".

Oh ok - so that's why I was still unsure why 2021-2023 isn't significant. But I guess it is before adjusting the p-value.

@KatherineChau the Bonferroni method is too conservative. The Holm modification (the default in the R p.adjust() function and I suspect also in dunnTest()) provides the same protection from false positives while providing more power to detect true differences.

@EdM Yes, FSA::dunnTest is, according to its documentation, "largely a wrapper for the dunn.test function in dunn.test". One important difference when calling FSA::dunnTest is that "the p-values are adjusted by default with the “holm” method, and two-sided p-values are returned by default. See dunn.test function in dunn.test for more details underlying these computations.". The original dunn.test defaults to not adjusting p-values.
